# Building Lists of Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building an app that allows dancers to create "round" or lists of dance moves. I have a moves model and a rounds model. I'd like to allow users to select their available moves and add them to a round.
I'm not quite sure what the associations need to be between these models. Right now the moves model belongs_to :round and the set model has_many :moves.

I don't necessarily understand how to add the moves to a round. As in Round #1 contains, move1, move2, move3. I'm confused because having the round_id on the move itself doesn't seem to make sense in this situation because users are adding moves to a round when the round is created, not when the move is created.

Basically the idea is, I need to be able to create a new list and add associated moves to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a additional table that will track all the moves corresponding to rounds;

```
class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :roundmoves
     has_many :rounds, :through => :roundmoves
end

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :roundmoves
     has_many :moves, :through => :roundmoves
end

class RoundMove < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :round
     belongs_to :move
end
```

Check the guides for a nice example of that:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm using a has_many through elsewhere on the site, but I guess I'm just not getting how to build that form where I have the current round and can add moves to it.

Comment: Hm, first thing that comes to my mind is to try going with nested attributes, in your `round` model: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :roundmoves` ,
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will watch. I think I understand what I need to do.